# Kusto - Materialized View on latest version of rows

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a Table called 'metadata', that contains a list of Parameter and ParamterValue that is partitioned by a TestId. Everytime a Test is changed, the Test will be reingested to Azure Data Explorer with a never Version.

My overall goal is to:

1. Define a Function (GetTestsFromSearch) that takes a Parameter (dynamic) of key value pairs, that lets me Query all Tests (Of latest version) for a match of the Key/Value pairs:

```
( {{"Search param1", "Search value1"},{"Search param2", "Search value2"}}
```

Example

```
GetTestsFromSearch({{"ProjectId", "SturnProject"},{"Product Name", "Nacelle "}})
```

Should return

| TestId | Version |
| --- | --- |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | 3 |
| ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454 | 1 |

from the example metadata table below

2. Another Goal is to Create a Materialized View that contains only latest metadata for each Test (Explained below table)

**Example of metadata table**

| TestId | TestName | Parameter | ParameterValue | Version |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | ProjectId | SturnProject | 1 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | Product Category | 2MW | 1 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | Project Start Date | 2022-02-03 | 1 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | ProjectId | SturnProject | 2 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | Product Category | 2MW | 2 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | Project Start Date | 2022-02-03 | 2 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | ProjectId | SturnProject | 3 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | Product Category | 2MW | 3 |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | MyTest | Project Start Date | 2022-02-03 | 3 |
| ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454 | MyTest | ProjectId | SturnProject | 1 |
| ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454 | MyTest | Project State | Open | 1 |
| ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454 | MyTest | Product Name | Nacelle | 1 |

Over time there will be thousands of Tests in several different Versions, and hence I anticipate, that it would be a good idea to create a **Materialized View**, that only maintains the Latest Versions of each Test - I have tried to create the view as:

```
metadata
| summarize arg_max(Version,*) by TestId
```

But this only gives me one Parameter and Parameter Value for each TestId/Version, not the entire result set of the Test.

- Can anyone point me in the right direction for this materialized view?

I have included an example of a metadata table as DataTable, which can be used in kusto directly.

Metadata Table as DataTable

```
datatable (TestId: string, Name: string, Parameter: string, ParameterValue: string, Version: int) [
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Report, DMS number","1234-231",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project name","Thor3",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","GTRS reference","gtrs",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Product Category","2MW",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project number","TE-12321",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DUT responsible person","ANFRB3",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test execution person","ANFRB3",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project Manager","ANFRB3",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DVPR, DMS number","1234-1234",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DVRE, DMS number","1231-1213",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Start Date","2022-02-23T00:00:00.0000000Z",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Category","Verification safety",int(3),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","GTRS reference","gtrs",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project number","TE-12321",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DUT responsible person","ANFRB2",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test execution person","ANFRB2",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project Manager","ANFRB2",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DVPR, DMS number","1234-1234",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DVRE, DMS number","1231-1213",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Start Date","2022-02-23T00:00:00.0000000Z",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Category","Verification safety",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Product Category","2MW",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project name","Thor3",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Report, DMS number","1234-231",int(2),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Category","Verification safety",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project Manager","ANFRB",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","GTRS reference","gtrs",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Product Category","2MW",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project name","Thor3",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Project number","TE-12321",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DUT responsible person","ANFRB",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test execution person","ANFRB",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DVPR, DMS number","1234-1234",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Report, DMS number","1234-231",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","DVRE, DMS number","1231-1213",int(1),
    "fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0","ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST","Test Start Date","2022-02-23T00:00:00.0000000Z",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","GTRS reference","gtrs232",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Product Category","4MW",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Project name","Myproject",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Project number","43324534",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","DUT responsible person","ANFRB",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Test execution person","ANFRB",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Project Manager","ANFRB",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","DVPR, DMS number","435123454",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Test Report, DMS number","123123123",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","DVRE, DMS number","12312312312",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Test Start Date","2022-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Test Category","Verification functionality",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Test facility","CHE",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Test rig","rig23",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Sample ID","1",int(1),
    "ea5b688c-b61f-4c5b-bb87-af2eac94d454","ANFRB2-TEST","Link to test data","asdfsafdsdfa",int(1)
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If most tests include same properties (as in your example), you can consider changing the schema to a wide schema, in which each run (`Version`) of a `TestId` and `Name` is a single record. The result schema would look like the output of the following:

```
**datatable**
| extend pack(Parameter, ParameterValue)
| summarize make_bag(Column1) by TestId, Name, Version
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag_Column1)
```

Then, you can set up a materialized view with the following aggregation that will provide what you're looking for IIUC:

```
T | summarize arg_max(Version, *) by TestId, Name
```

To switch from the schema in your example to the suggested one, you can either change your ingestion pipeline to ingest in new schema format, or use an [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) for the transformation. If you choose the latter, avoid using [bag_unpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-unpackplugin) plugin in the update policy function. Instead, project the columns you need explicitly, to avoid a non-deterministic schema.

Another alternative, is keeping all properties in single dynamic column, as in the result of:

```
**datatable**
| extend pack(Parameter, ParameterValue)
| summarize make_bag(Column1) by TestId, Name, Version
```

And using same materialized view definition as above.

For the 1st question - using the 2nd suggested schema, you can try something like the following:

```
let GetTestsFromSearch = (Filter:dynamic)
{
    T
    | extend pack(Parameter, ParameterValue)
    | summarize Properties = make_bag(Column1) by TestId, Name, Version  
    | summarize arg_max(Version, *) by TestId, Name
    | extend Filter
    | mv-apply Filter on 
    ( 
        extend key=tostring(bag_keys(Filter)[0]) 
        | extend expected = tostring(Filter[key]), actual = tostring(Properties[key])
        | summarize count(), countif(actual == expected)
        | where count_  == countif_
    )
};
GetTestsFromSearch(dynamic({"Test Category" : "Verification safety", "Project name" : "Thor3"}));
```

| TestId | Name | Version | Properties | count_ | countif_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fc76aa10-5cf8-447e-95f6-3bd801ef2ed0 | ANFRB-FILEVIEW-TEST | 3 | { "Test Report, DMS number": "1234-231", "Project name": "Thor3", "GTRS reference": "gtrs", "Product Category": "2MW", "Project number": "TE-12321", "DUT responsible person": "ANFRB3", "Test execution person": "ANFRB3", "Project Manager": "ANFRB3", "DVPR, DMS number": "1234-1234", "DVRE, DMS number": "1231-1213", "Test Start Date": "2022-02-23T00:00:00.0000000Z", "Test Category": "Verification safety" } | 2 | 2 |

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Its clever with the schema that is reduced to collecting all parameters and their values into a single dynamic column :) That works excellent. The only problem I see is with the GetTestsFromSearch function. If i call it with the following args: GetTestsFromSearch(dynamic({"Test Category" : "Verification safety", "Project name" : "Myproject"})) I would have expected it would return 2 tests in the result, since 'Myproject' and 'Verification safety' are values that exsist in 2 different tests.

Comment: But it does not return anything, because the function expects the paramters specified in the args to be in the same test. But the function should look in "any" test, that might have the specifiec Parameter and ParamterValue.

Comment: Ok - found the issue. Modified your suggested function to:  .create-or-alter function  SearchParameters(ParametersFilter: dynamic) {
TestsWithParametersAsJson
    | summarize arg_max(Version, *) by TestId
    | extend ParametersFilter
    | mv-apply ParametersFilter on 
    ( 
        extend key=tostring(bag_keys(ParametersFilter)[0]) 
        | extend expected = tostring(ParametersFilter[key]), actual = tostring(Parameters[key])
        | summarize ParameterCount = count(), ParameterMatch = countif(actual == expected)
        | where ParameterMatch> 0
    )
}

Comment: And it now returns the Count that matched for each test :) Thanks a bunch for your help @yifats much appreciated.